# Kotlin array of buttons are all null

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Creating an array of buttons

```
    val buttons = arrayOf(spot0, spot1, spot2, spot3, spot4, spot5, spot6)
    Log.v("array", "spot0=" + buttons[0])

    images.shuffle()
    val randomnumber = (0..5).random()

    buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(images[randomnumber])
```

Gets this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null
>   object reference

and this log output:

> V/array: spot0=null

This is Kotlin so I shouldn't have to call findViewById from what I can tell.

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' is added to my build.gradle

Button is setup in xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/spot0"
    android:text="zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="131dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="131dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="131dp"
    android:background="@drawable/heart"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.565"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I'm attempting to randomize my button images and attempting to do it via an array. How can I go about this?

Comment: where are you initializing `buttons` array?

Comment: Make sure your code is inside onCreate method. If you try to initialize the buttons array before onCreate then it will cause some problem..

Comment: The first usage of the array in my code is what is above, but it didn't copy paste over all the text. I am not initializing it anywhere else. It is in onCreate. The full text is:

val buttons :Array<ImageButton!> = arrayOf(spot0, spot1, spot2, spot3, spot4, spot5, spot6)

Comment: val buttons = arrayOf(spot0, spot1, spot2, spot3, spot4, spot5, spot6)
        buttons[0] = spot0
        Log.v("array", "spot0=" + buttons[0])

That still outputs a null in the log.

Comment: Do you call `setContentView(R.id.your_layout)` method before initializing the array?

Comment: Ok, I outputted Log.v("button value", "spot0=" + spot0) and it looks like the button's themselves are null.

Comment: When I call setContentLayout it gives the error: Unresolved reference: setContentLayout. I'm in a fragment class.

Comment: Call `setContentView`, not setContentLayout.

Comment: Same error. "Unresolved reference: setContentView"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you are in `Activity`:

You should call `setContentView(R.id.your_layout)` method in Activity's `onCreate()` method before accessing the views and initializing the array.

### If you are in `Fragment`:

Try to access the views and initialize the array in `onViewCreated()` method.

Comment: I'm in onCreate(). setContentView returns the error: "Unresolved reference: setContentView"

setContentView works fine in the MainActivity.kt but it isn't working in this fragment class that I'm working in.

Comment: @SiobhanS I've edited my answer. Try to do your things in `onViewCreated()` method.

Comment: Yes! This worked! Thank you!!! I moved the code to onViewCreated() and it worked perfectly.

Comment: great. that's because in Fragment's `onCreate` method the layout is not set and views are not initialized yet.